# Filtering a nested field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter some documents on ElasticSearch 7.11.

My index has the following mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "recArrNested": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "nBTxt": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "nBInt": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    },
    "recNested": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "nAInt": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "nATxt": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "recId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

I have records which looks like that:

```
{
  "recArrNested": [
    {
      "nBTxt": "juliette",
      "nBInt": 10
    },
    {
      "nBTxt": "alpha",
      "nBInt": 42
    },
    {
      "nBTxt": "kilo",
      "nBInt": 11
    }
  ],
  "recNested": {
    "nAInt": 1,
    "nATxt": "manual"
  },
  "recId": "1alpha"
}
```

My goal is to filter the records which have a `recArrNested.nBTxt` equals to its `recNested.nAInt` NATO corresponding phonetic alphabet (alpha -> 1, bravo -> 2, and so on).

I have generated the following query:

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recNested.nAInt": {
                          "value": "1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recArrNested.nBTxt": {
                          "value": "alpha"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recNested.nAInt": {
                          "value": "2"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recArrNested.nBTxt": {
                          "value": "bravo"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "recId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "track_scores": false
}
```

Sadly the above example document does not match.
Do you have any suggestion to tackle that query properly?

Comment: I just ingested your example document, ran the query and the document matched. Are you using any special mappings?

Comment: In order for this to work you probably need to make `recArrNested` and `recNested` of type `nested` in your index mapping, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have forgot to create it, but it does not change (even with `nested` instead of `object`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason for declaring `recNested` to be of the type `nested` -- it'll suffice to keep `recArrNested` actually `nested` because you're dealing with arrays of objects that [would've otherwise been flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects).

In accordance with your current mapping you'll want to use [`nested` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) whenever applicable:

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recNested.nAInt": {
                          "value": "1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "recArrNested",        <--
                        "query": {
                          "term": {
                            "recArrNested.nBTxt": {
                              "value": "alpha"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "recNested.nAInt": {
                          "value": "2"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "recArrNested",        <--
                        "query": {
                          "term": {
                            "recArrNested.nBTxt": {
                              "value": "bravo"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "recId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "track_scores": false
}
```